# Shortest path not recognising network as connected

Tags: qgis, network, shortest-path

I'm trying to use a grid network that I have created to find the shortest path between two points accounting for directional wind-speed.  The problem I'm running into is that the shortest path feature in QGIS doesn't seem to be able to turn corners in my network.  It can find the path for any points in a straight line, but any points that deviate in longitude or latitude it gives an error saying that there is no path.

I thought it might be a problem with my data so I just created a naive grid and I get the same result.

I'm pretty new to QGIS so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you provide us with the data or a subset of it?

Comment: At this point, I'm just trying to make it work with a grid created with the grid function.  But my original data is a series of line strings that intersect from a csv file using wkt code

Comment: Like this:  
dw_y  uw_y  dw_x  uw_x  av_wind   wkt_geo where the first four columns are coordinates, the last column is a linestring concatenating them and av_wind is wind speed